# Sampling without replacement is IID?

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ denote $n$ values obtained when the samples is drawn without replacement from a finite population, we know they are not independent, but are they identically distributed?

Comment: Considering that you draw from the same population, they must be identically distributed.

Comment: If the population has one distinct, non-overlapping property, then yes. Drawing from an urn with R red marbles and W white marbles without replacement. The $i^{th}$ draw of a red marble will always have probability R/(R+W).  One can show, that the hypergeometric distribution is a sum of correlated Bernoulli random variables.

Comment: @PeterStrouvelle If you drew a red marble the first time, isn't the probability of drawing a red ball the second time $(R-1)/(R+W-1)$?

Comment: @ytnb Since they are not independent, you should not expect a probability to stay the same when you condition on another event.  But the probability the second draw is red (not knowing the first ball's colour) is the same as the probability the first draw is red; it only changes if you know the colour of the first ball.  The equality  is due to "exchangeability" of the balls.

Comment: @ytnb no, conditional on knowing what has been drawn before, the probability to draw another red marble decreases. But without this knowledge, it stays constant. Exchangeability just means that any draw behaves like the first draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you draw uniformly from a population $ \mathfrak{ X } $ with $ | \mathfrak{ X } | = N $, you should have that for any $ k = 1, \dots, n $ and $ x \in \mathfrak{ X } $,
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{P} \{ X_{k} = x \} 
  & = 
  \mathbb{P} \{ \text{"x not drawn before"} \} \mathbb{P} \{ \text{"draw x"} | \text{"x not drawn before"} \} 
  = 
  \frac{ N - k - 1 }{ N } 
  \frac{ 1 }{ N - k - 1 } 
  = 
  \frac{1}{ N }.
\end{align}
This does not depend on $ k $.
So the $ X_{1}, \dots, X_{n} $ share the same distribution.

Answer (score 1):

> If you drew a red marble the first time, isn't the probability of
> drawing a red ball the second time (R−1)/(R+W−1) ?

Yes. But the key point is another one. The probability that a red ball is drawn at the i-th time is still $\frac{R}{R+W}$. Let $x_i$ denotes  the event, where at the i-th draw a red ball is selected. The calculation for the second time ($i=2$) then is

$$\begin{align*}  
P(X=x_2)=\frac{R}{R+W}\cdot \frac{R-1}{R+W-1}+\frac{W}{R+W}\cdot \frac{R}{R+W-1} \\ =\frac{R\cdot \require{cancel} \cancel{(R-1+W)}}{(R+W)\cdot \require{cancel} \cancel{(R-1+W)}}=\frac{R}{R+W}
\end{align*}$$

Here we have to regard both paths: $\textrm{WR}$ and $\textrm{RR}$. Similar calculations can be made for all $i$, with the same result.